# enable enterprise geodatabase error

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am trying to enable an enterprise database. 
I right click > enable and then navigate to our organizations keycode file. 
I get this error: Attribute Column Not found... (see screenshot)

[image: error message from esri]

This process has worked in the past but maybe IT has tweaked things or since 10.4 install this may have also changed things?

specs:

ArcGIS 10.4 (Advanced License)
SQL Server 2008
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)

Comment: The important part of the error message didn't make it into the question: "Fail to enable database option ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT"  See the third bullet in [Whats New: Geodata](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/introduction/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-BFAB27B8-04AA-4C21-90D0-C63B7A7A4E59)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A google on "ArcGIS READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION" returned a "What's new in ArcMap" 10.4 documentation reference.  In the [Geodata](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/introduction/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-BFAB27B8-04AA-4C21-90D0-C63B7A7A4E59) section it states (third bullet, emphasis mine):

> Beginning with ArcGIS 10.4, geodatabases in SQL Server require the SQL
>   Server database options READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and
>   ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION be set to ON. When you upgrade your
>   geodatabase in SQL Server, the Upgrade Geodatabase tool sets these in
>   the database. When you create a geodatabase in SQL Server using the
>   Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool, the tool sets these options in the
>   database. **If you use the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase tool to create
>   a geodatabase, you must either set these options to ON in the database
>   before you run the tool, or grant the geodatabase administrator the
>   permission to ALTER the database.** If the geodatabase administrator has
>   ALTER database permission, the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase sets
>   READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to ON in the
>   database.
>
> To use ArcGIS 10.4 with SQL Server databases or 10.3.1 or earlier
>   release geodatabases, you must manually set on READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT
>   in the database.

Comment: Great, I have now enabled this using this: [link] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx. I now have another error that I will research:

"The version of your database server is not supported"

Comment: Probaby addressed by the [requirements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm#GUID-0714EC60-B387-453D-A18D-6B4034196388) page (2008R2 support ended at 10.3.1)

Comment: interesting, I have existing 2008R2 databases that work fine but it won't let me 'enable' a geodatabase for a newly created one - since upgrading to 10.4. Has support ended but existing DB's still work perhaps?

Comment: Unsupported is unsupported. I would expect old databases to fail in unexpected ways.